# How to install driver for USB Wi-Fi on Linux Mint

Tags: wireless-networking, drivers

I had the misfortune of buying a Sabrent USB Wi-Fi adapter. The box says it’s good for Linux but no instructions inside, not instructions on disk and the person who picks up their support line cheerfully informs me: “No one here knows anything about Linux. You’re on your own.”

I found a [knowledge base for their products](http://sabrent.com/support/knowledgebase.php?article=34) but the two videos for Linux installation are “No longer available.”

But there is a Linux tar file on the CD. How can I use it to install it?

I’ve already tried plugging in the adapter and nothing seems to happen.

Comment: First, some problems with your question: You need to state the **exact name of your Linux distribution and the version.** Also include whether it's 32-bit or 64-bit. Don't approximate the version or the name; get the **exact** name/version. Second, you need to run `lspci -nnvv` on your Linux box and retrieve the PCI ID of the Sabrent adapter so we can see whether it's supported in mainline Linux, before trying to get you installing the driver on the CD. Just post your whole `lspci -nnvv` output in a code block in your question.

Comment: Also, there is no such thing as generic instructions for how to "install" a tar file. A tar file is just an archive of other files. How would you "install" a zip file on Windows? Well, it depends on what's inside, of course! It could just be a text file saying "Sorry, this isn't supported". Or, it could be source code to compile a driver. Or it could be a binary installer. Or any number of things. You'd have to extract it and check it out.

Comment: It is a USB device, so post `lsusb` output.   `sudo tail -n 25 -f /var/log/messages`   and then plug in your USB wifi adapter.  Post what it says.  `cat /proc/version`  `uname -a`

Answer (score 2):

1. Open contents in CD and then copy and paste folder Linux onto desktop or downloads folder. (anywhere really)
2. Go to where you have copied folder, right click folder and select properties.
3. Select Permissions tab and change all the folder access options to "create and delete files". (This stops the file from just being a read only). Now select Apply permissions to enclosed files.
4. Go back into linux folder and then driver folder. You will see a folder like rtl8192EU_linux_v4.3.8_12406.20140929.tar.gz. Right click and select extract here.
5. Now, return to linux folder, right click it again and select open in terminal.
6. Enter this command: `chmod +x install.sh` (it may prompt you for your password)
7. Then enter this command: `sudo ./install.sh`
8. It will now install the necessary driver to allow your USB wireless adapter to be detected and work. (Sometimes you will have to restart computer or laptop).
9. Finally go to wireless connection icon at bottom right or top right depending on what linux distro you are using. You should see your usb detected. Connect.

Job done.